# Indicator Vector based on two Character vectors' common element

Tags: r, if-statement, vector, char

I have a character vector:

```
beta = c("V1","V2","V3","V4","V5")
```

and another character vector:

```
beta1 = c("V1","V3")
```

Now I want to create a num vector `alpha` of length 5 in the following way: if `"V_{i}"` is present in `beta1` then i-th index at vector `alpha` will take value `1`. Else the i-th index value will be `0`.

For example, in the above case, `alpha` is `c(1,0,1,0,0)` because "V1" and "V3" are present in `beta1`

If `beta1` was `c("V4","V5")` then `alpha` would be `c(0,0,0,1,1)`

How can I do this in R in an efficient way?

Comment: One doubt, suppose the 'beta1' is having length greater than 'beta', would you want to return the length for 'beta'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `%in%` to find the elements in first vector that are also in second as a `logical` vector.  As the TRUE/FALSE values are stored as 1/0, coerce it to binary with `as.integer`

```
as.integer(beta %in% beta1)
```

Answer (score 0):

with `match`:

```
indicator <- rep(0, length(beta))
indicator[match(beta1, beta)] <- 1
indicator
# [1] 1 0 1 0 0
```